# Drupal 7 custom pages and URIs

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, hook

I encountered small problem which I cant figure out.
I have a website, and there will be set of pages which will be custom made ( but with template of the page ), just the custom content.

For example:
http://mypage.com/?q=stuff

I read about hooking and made file - page--stuff.tpl.php and duplicated page.tpl.php, but page title is - Page not found and i don't i'm doing it right, because of duplicating page.tpl.php

Those pages will include custom hand written modules and custom PHP code, but overall layout will be same as other nodes.

How i could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a page which is not linked to a node you have to implement [hook_menu](http://www.ecosia.org/url?url=https://api.drupal.org/hook_menu&v=4&i=0&q=drupal%20hook_menu&p=0&tr=210000&at=0&ar=0&ab=0&mr=0&ir=0&kgr=0&nr=0&iar=0&sr=0) in a self-made module.

```
function MODULENAME_menu() {
  return array("stuff" => array( // link (in your case: http://mypage.com/stuff)
  'title' => "stuff", // title of the page
  'page callback' => "themefunction", // logic for the content
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK // there are more types, read hoo_menu() for further details
  );
}
```

You can substitute *themefunction* with anything you like, but you have to implement it!

```
function themefunction() {
  // do some theming output stuff like:
  $items['hello'] = "Hello World!"; // your variable output
  return theme('stuff_theme', array('items' => $items)); // say Drupal to theme that stuff in your default page-template
}
```

Then you need to register your theme in Drupal by implementing [hook_theme](http://www.ecosia.org/url?url=https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7&v=4&i=0&q=hook_theme&p=0&tr=47200&at=0&ar=0&ab=0&mr=0&ir=0&kgr=0&nr=0&iar=0&sr=0) (that is also don in your main module file)

```
function MODULENAME_menu() {
  return array(
    'stuff_theme' => array( // file name of the template WITHOUT .tpl.php
      'variables' => array( 
        'items' => NULL // variables that are assigned to the template
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Finally you need to create the template *stuff_theme.tpl.php* (in the module-folder):

```
<div><?= $items['hello']; ?></div>
```

Unfortunately that's the only way to create truly custom content-pages. For small code-injections into a node you can also enable the **PHP filter** module.